# how to convert datetype of text data

Tags: database, dolphindb

I have a list of dates stored as Date in my text file, and I want the import database to be stored as Month.
In this case, how do I convert the datatype of the date column? Is there a function in dolphindb?

Answer (score 0):

One of this functions can help you, `replaceColumn` / `datetimeParse`.

- Note: `replaceColumn` is available since v0.99.